# Why is my combobox/picker is doing dropdown when I click outside its area?

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.forms, uwp, picker

This particular `CustomPicker` it opens the element list by itself when I interact with component.

The only problem right now is that the first `CustomPicker` every time I touch or focus in other component, enter to the form `ContentPage` or do other action, opens the elements list automatically and change the focus to itself.

It´s kind of anoying and I want to ask if, is there´s something I can do? Maybe I'm missing a property. Maybe the class `CustomPicker` need something in particular.

I'm currently working on a UWP/Android register form. This form is composed with `Entries`, `Buttons` and `Pickers` (a `CustomPicker`).

I really don´t know what method triggers the open or close of the `CustomPicker`.

I checked other `CustomPickers` in the source and they do not behaved like this. The only difference is that they don't have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event nor the `HeightRequest` property set.

The version of `Xamarin.Forms` the VS Solutin is the `2.3.4`

MAYOR UPDATE: I changed the `CustomPicker` component for a regular `Picker` and is behaving the same way.

**ANOTHER MAYOR UPDATE:** It turns out that `ScrollView` as soon is focus it always focus the first enable element of the what is inside within. Since I click outside the area but inside the `ScrollView` it detects the focus on the `ScrollView` then the focus on the first element.

I put on the an `Entry` first then a `CustomPicker` and now it always focus on the `Entry` when the `ContentPage` appears.

```cs
// This is the CustomPicker class
// It is not exported to a Custom Render
    public class CustomPicker : Picker
    {
        public CustomPicker()
        {
            Image = "ic_arrow_drop_down";
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), 
                                      typeof(string), typeof(CustomPicker), 
                                      string.Empty);

        public string Image
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

```xml
<ScrollView>
<ContentView>
   <Entry x:Name="someText" /> <!-- Fast solution -->
</ContenView>
<ContentView>

    <CustomRenders:CustomPicker 
        x:Name="comboTypeClient"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TypeClientList, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding TypeClientName}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding TypeClientSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
        HeightRequest="40"
        SelectedIndexChanged="comboTypeClient_SelectedIndexChanged" />
</ContentView>
</ScrollView>
```

The `CustomPicker` or `Picker` must not open the element list when I interact with the rest of the form.

Comment: What is this ContentView doing here and what happens if you set Horizontal and Vertical aliggments of the control to Left/Top?

Comment: ```ContentView``` is old code. Before ```CustomPicker``` were set programatically.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce your question, could you please share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?